# How to import a backend module class into an app module in android studio

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

In my android project, i have two modules,

- App module
- backend module

I want to import a backend module class into one of my app module class. but when i try to import it like this

```
import com.me.you.backend.entities
```

i get an error `Error:(52, 58) error: package com.me.you.backend.entities does not exist`

The next thing that i tried is to compile my backend module in my app's `build.gradle` like this

```
dependencies {
....
compile project(':backend')
}
```

**But** i get **13 warnings!** of this type

```
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1 is ignored 
for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
```

**And when i run my app module, i get this error**

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
```

> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/AuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.class

**Question**

How can i successfully import my backend class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to add dependancy on backend module in my app module's `build.gradle` like this

```
compile project(path: `:backend`, configuration: `android-endpoints`)
```

**After this i rebuild my project** (Build > Rebuild project).  and everything was ok.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to create a new module "Commons". There you can put all shared classes between 'Backend' and 'app' by adding on your gradle files:

```
compile project(':commons')
```

Comment: @johny_kb      suppose i create that module, put a backend class in it. that backend class has a method that calls another backend class. in the end, its like puting all backend classes in another module(copy pasting). and when i `compile project(':commons')` i will end up getting the same same warnings and errors!

Comment: tell me if I misunderstand what you are saying: you have a class that has a reference with a backend class, and you want to share it with app, so client directly can call this method? If it is a control class, I think you can't share it between two modules. Solution with 'commons' requires in its package domain classes, shared between server and client. As example, if I have a domain class "com.aproject.User", I can put it in "Commons" module and then, in backend and app I can import it.